# Draw.io embeded documentation configuration parameters

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

I'm on a project with embedded draw.io integration, only, the documentation part of the possible "configuration" doesn't seem to redirect to the right place.
Below is the screen print I made.
It leads to: https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/diagram-editor-configuration.html, but there are no parameters that can be passed to the iframe in event (JSON)

For the moment I have for example found this by searching for :

```
{
   action: "configure"
   config: {
      defaultFonts: ["Tahoma"]
   }
}
```

But, I search the completely documentation about all parameters.
Do you have this link page ?
Thanks,

Nice day

https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/embed-mode

[embeded screenshot documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyPtH.png)

Answer (score 1):

While browsing other places again, I just came across this url that surely solves my problem.

FAQ complete:
https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/

Part of configuration:
https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/configure-diagram-editor